# Is a Parselmouth immune to the effects of the stare of the Basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk, parseltongue

We see in the Chamber of Secrets when Tom Riddle summons the Basilisk, he looked at the Basilisk's eyes directly.

[image]

So are they immune to the effects, or is it just the controller?

Comment: Riddle is a phantom and Harry didn't see the eyes (Fawkes plucked its eyes out)

Comment: @NKCampbell - except that the eyes had been shown to partially work on the insufficiently living (Nearly Headless Nick).  So this is actually a better Q than the usual.

Comment: Riddle is less real than even NHN in this case. That's the whole point of his plan

Comment: Is the basilisk stare even something that's automatic or does the basilisk have to actively concentrate on using that power.  If so then it could just not be using it when looking at Riddle.

Comment: NHN is a ghost. Riddle is some kind of Horcrux Entity, which we know can be destroyed by Basilisk Venom, but apparently can't be destroyed by a Basilik's stare.

Comment: My guess would be that Basilisk venom causes both physical and magical damage (which is why the diary is damaged by it), but the stare only works on living entities. The Diary isn't a living entity, and is the only way to harm the Horcrux manifestations, so the stare doesn't effect it.

Comment: @DavidS NHN isn't a living entity either, but he was still petrified as a result of looking the Basilisk directly in the eyes. Riddle wasn't affected in any way. It could also be that the Basilisk has some control over its stare ability, and because "it only obeys me", the Basilisk is actually choosing not to "Death Stare" Riddle.

Comment: From FB: *since Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths, they are as dangerous to most Dark wizards as to anybody else*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57463/discussion-on-question-by-kyle-v-is-a-parselmouth-immune-to-the-effects-of-the-s).

Comment: That image does not show Tom looking directly at the basilisk's eyes.

Comment: @OrangeDog a second or so before this picture, he looks directly into the basilisk's eyes

Comment: @KyleV would a picture of that not be better then?

Comment: @OrangeDog couldn't find one

Comment: Tom Riddle's memory _knew_ that Harry is a Parselmouth from Ginny; this is mentioned in the book. If all Parselmouths were immune to Basilisk stares by design, it is reasonable to expect the well-read Tom Riddle to know this, in which case he wouldn't have bothered to set the Basilisk on Harry.

Comment: @NKCampbell Tom Riddle could wield Harry's wand and even cast the Flagrate spell with it. He was physically more real than Nearly Headless Nick.

Comment: not at first @KyleV - only after slowly drawing life force from Ginny was he being more corporeal :)

Answer (score 47):

#### There's no canon proof either way. Even if they aren't, there’d be ways around it.

- They’d know that the looking into the eyes of the basilisk can
  kill, so they'd be careful not to.

  Most of the basilisk victims were probably caught off guard by the presence of a basilisk. The Parselmouth controlling it would both know of its existence, and that its stare is deadly. So, if they can be killed by it, they'd probably be careful not to look into its eyes. That should be easy enough. A basilisk is very large, so even if they need to look at it, they can just look somewhere else. In addition, presuming basilisks have functional eyelids, if there's a chance that they might look at its eyes accidentally, they can just tell it to close its eyes.
- It's possible the basilisk can control if its stare kills,
  and not use it on the Parselmouth.

  There's no canon information available on whether the basilisk is actually trying to kill each of its victims. We do know, however, that each of its victims are people who Tom Riddle would have wanted dead. No one died who Tom would have wanted to remain living. It's at least possible that the basilisk has to actually be trying to kill someone with its stare for it to work. In that case, the Parselmouth would be completely safe, once it's not intending to kill.
- Tom, at least, was only a memory, so the stare of a basilisk might
  not have any effect on him.

  As for how it could work on a ghost and not on him, he says himself that he was less than a ghost when his Horcruxes were the only thing keeping him alive.

  > "I was less than spirit, less than the meanest ghost... but still I was alive." 
  > <sub><sup>*– Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>
- When Harry looks at the basilisk, Fawkes had already torn out its eyes.

  Harry's ability to look at the basilisk is irrelevant to his ability to speak Parseltongue. A basilisk can kill with its stare, but that's presuming it has eyes. No eyes, no stare. That's almost certainly why Fawkes tore out its eyes to begin with. The phoenix isn't a characteristically violent creature, and neither is Fawkes specifically. The logical explanation for him resorting to violence like eye gouging would be to neutralize the basilisk's most powerful weapon.

Comment: Which leads to the next question...wouldn't Fawkes have needed to look **at** its eyes to pluck them out?

Comment: +1. I especially like your second bullet-point; I'd always wondered how Riddle managed to specifically kill just the Muggle-borns, and your suggestion would resolve that nicely.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks! Yeah, it seems at least somewhat likely that the basilisk could control its stare. I'm glad you liked my suggestion! It would explain how Tom could target the basilisk attacks.

Comment: @T.E.D. Maybe phoenixes are immune to the basilisk stare.

Comment: @T.E.D. Not necessarily. If you and I are wrestling, I can probably poke you in the eyes even with mine closed. Fakes could have used peripheral vision or come up from an oblique angle. Lots of options.

Comment: @mbm29414 Another good suggestion. One way or another, I'm sure Fawkes, a near immortal phoenix, can handle himself. I don't think it's impossible that he could've managed to pluck out the basilisk's eyes.

Comment: @Bellatrix re: "what was changed" in the edit I proposed: I added four spaces to the beginning of each (non-bullet) paragraph, nothing more. It just looks better to align the paragraphs with the bullets they are supporting. No content changed.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh, okay! :) You can go ahead and do it then, and I'll approve it. I just didn't want to accept an edit where I couldn't figure out what was changed. You're right, it would look better formatted the way you suggest, with the bullets and paragraphs aligned. Thanks so much for explaining! :)

Comment: @Bellatrix Yeah, StackExchange did an absolutely rubbish job of showing what had changed. If I had seen that diff on one of my answers I'd have been suspicious, too. =)

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for understanding! :) Your edit is approved now! Again, thanks for everything! :)

Comment: @T.E.D.: Phoenix tears are the antivenom to Basilisk venom. I would presume that Phoenixes are immune to the deadly stare as well.

Comment: "Presuming basilisks have functional eyelids..." -- snakes don't have eyelids, and presumably the basilisk wouldn't either.

Comment: @DanielWagner, Bellatrix You can also check the markdown diff to see what changed in a case like this.

Comment: @Scimonster A basilisk is also a magical creature, as well as a snake, so that snakes don't have eyelids doesn't necessarily mean that the basilisk doesn't. Without canon information saying one way or another, we don't really know. "Presuming basilisks have functional eyelids" is just another way of saying "this is what could happen if they have functional eyelids".

Comment: @Scimonster I did check the difference. That was part of what made it confusing. The markdown made it look like everything in my answer was crossed out and rewritten, when all that was actually changed was the format. I couldn't figure out what the difference was, although I compared the wording of both answers. I didn't like not knowing what was changed about my answer, in case something important was changed and I just didn't see it, so I rolled it back to my original answer.

Comment: @Bellatrix I mean the markdown source diff, not the rendered output.

Comment: @Scimonster I had checked both, and still couldn't figure out how my answer was changed. Still, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Krumia - makes sense a phoenix might be immune, with an antidote to basilisks literally in its eyes, between its gaze and the snake's.  Though maybe it only works if said eyes are tearing up, or at least moist or something.  Antidote is for venom, yes, but no one said it wasn't also for the stare - just might be harder for a non-phoenix to have (or know to have) the antidote tears in their eyes when they need it.

Comment: Phoenixes are immune to the stare of a basilisk

Answer (score 7):

> The creation of Basilisks has been illegal since medieval times, although the practice is easily concealed by simply removing the chicken egg from beneath the toad when the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures comes to call. However, **since Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths, they are as dangerous to most Dark wizards as to anybody else**, and there have been no recorded sightings of Basilisks in Britain for at least four hundred years.
>   <sub>*Fantastic Beast and Where to Find Them* (2001 textbook) - Basilisk</sub>

I see two ways to interpret this statement:

1. > **since Basilisks are *uncontrollable* except by Parselmouths**, they are as dangerous to most Dark wizards as to anybody else

   The only advantage of a Parselmouth is their ability to control a basilisk, not being immune to its effects.
2. > since Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths, **they are as dangerous to *most* Dark wizards as to anybody else**

   Basilisks aren't dangerous to  Parselmouths.

Answer (score 3):

*No.* Parseltongue is a language, though an inherent one, and as such cannot afford the speaker immunity against the Basilisk. Tom Riddle is a 'ghost' conjured up by the diary - notice that the diary is down in the chamber? This 'ghost' of Riddle cannot be anywhere that the diary isn't, which is why he couldn't get to Harry *before* he convinced Ginny to throw the diary into the girl's bathroom so he could manipulate Harry into finding it. Meaning that because he is even less real than Nearly Headless Nick, who is momentarily paralysed by the Basilisk's stare, he can look it in the eye and not be affected. Think of it like this, the Tom Riddle we see is a ripple in time, a tiny fold that can interact and even manipulate things around him to a small extent, though he requires a source of power to feed off of, and that is Ginny. The only reason Harry can look the Basilisk in the eye after he'd been chased through those tunnels is because Fawkes tore its eyes out. Without its eyes, the Basilisk cannot use its magic, thus being unable to paralyse or kill anyone with its stare alone, which is why it goes from being passive-aggressive to physical aggression. Think about all the students it paralysed. Why didn't it try to bite them like it did Harry? Because its eyes had done the work. The students wouldn't die right away since they'd all seen the eyes indirectly - mirrors, pools of water, a camera - but like any coma patients, their bodies would eventually starve of nutrients and they'd die, meaning the Basilisk didn't need to actively attack anyone, and why it didn't finish them off by tearing out their throats (that, and it's a kid's book).

Conclusion; neither Tom Riddle, Harry Potter, or any other person who can talk Parseltongue is immune to the stare of a Basilisk. In fact, I'd go as far as to say that it had *always* been Riddle's plan to use a Horcrux to unleash the Basilisk when he was no longer at Hogwarts, thus removing the risk of it turning on him - he was a Mudblood, after all, and the Basilisk was raised by Slytherin himself to attack any non-purebloods - and that the one previous time it was unleashed was him basically taking it for a test drive.

Comment: "he was a Mudblood, after all, and the Basilisk was raised by Slytherin himself to attack any non-purebloods." Tom Riddle was a half-blood, not a Mudblood.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.

Comment: @KyleV - So you are implying that Potterverse bigots don't use the [one-drop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-drop_rule)?

Comment: @T.E.D., don't you remember Harry taunting the Death Eaters about that?  Quote is something like, "Voldemort?  He's a half-blood, did you know that?  Yeah, his mum was a witch, but his dad was a muggle!  Or has he been telling you lot he's pureblood?"

Comment: *"Parseltongue is a language, though an inherent one, and as such cannot afford the speaker immunity against the Basilisk."* Why not? Citation needed! The gene combination that allows communicating with snakes could also grant immunity to snake venoms and death stares. I'm not saying that *it does*, but you'd need proof to discard that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could ever happen is if that Parselmouth, (Tom Riddle, in this case) wasn't completely alive.
Here's why: After Harry had already entered in the Chamber of Secrets attempting to save Ginny, Tom tried to kill him by having summoned the Basilisk out of Salazar Slytherin's mouth, yet he looked straight into those murderous eyes before it attacked Harry, and he survived that because he was only a 'memory, only because he came out of his diary, which was his first-ever Horcrux.
However, if Tom tried to do that when he was a student at Hogwarts, that would've immediately killed him.